# Kubernetes 1.8 dashboard configurations fails with error "no kind "Role" is registered for version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1"

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have issue with kubernetes dashboard installation, appreciate your comments and solutions.

**ERROR:** 
unable to decode "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard-head.yaml": no kind "Role" is registered for version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1" unable to decode "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard-head.yaml": no kind "RoleBinding" is registered for version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1" unable to decode "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard-head.yaml": no kind "Deployment" is registered for version "apps/v1beta2"

**kubectl version** 
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"5", GitVersion:"v1.5.2", GitCommit:"269f928217957e7126dc87e6adfa82242bfe5b1e", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-07-03T15:31:10Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"} Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"5", GitVersion:"v1.5.2", GitCommit:"269f928217957e7126dc87e6adfa82242bfe5b1e", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-07-03T15:31:10Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

**kubectl api-versions** 
apps/v1beta1 authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1 authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1 autoscaling/v1 batch/v1 certificates.k8s.io/v1alpha1 extensions/v1beta1 policy/v1beta1 rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1alpha1 storage.k8s.io/v1beta1 v1

**Pods Status**
kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard-3725693093-zm11m   0/1   CrashLoopBackOff

Comment: kube-system   kube-dns-v10-1729x                      3/4       CrashLoopBackOff   3036       21d
kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard-3725693093-zm11m   0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   21         1h

Comment: Do you have a RBAC enabled cluster?

Comment: I have tried doing that while starting api-server --authorization-mode=RBAC, but it was not working as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have an [RBAC enabled cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authorization/rbac/), you won't be able to use RBAC objects, such as Role. That's why when trying to create a `Role` object, it fails saying it doesn't know anything about `Role` objects.
[From the docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authorization/#authorization-modules)

> When specified “RBAC” (Role-Based Access Control) uses the “rbac.authorization.k8s.io” API group to drive authorization decisions, allowing admins to dynamically configure permission policies through the Kubernetes API.

You also need a more recent kubectl version, as mentioned [in this comment](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/48629#issuecomment-334632061). RBAC requires at least kubectl 1.6 and you have 1.5.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.

So, how can we enable RBAC on k8s cluster, is there any specific set of commands?
I have used the same k8s https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authorization/rbac/ reference, but i am not to follow what will be the next steps in my case.

Comment: Enabling RBAC is just a matter of passing the --authorization-mode=RBAC parameter to the api-server, as you mentioned earlier. You don't need to do anything else to enable it. Did you get the `no kind "Role"` error even enabling RBAC?

Comment: i tried re-starting the api-serve and endup with below error.
systemctl start kube-apiserver --authorization-mode=RBAC
systemctl: unrecognized option '--authorization-mode=RBAC'

Comment: wait a minute. You are passing the `--authorization-mode=RBAC` option to `systemctl`. You need to pass it to the api-server binary (the one that systemctl executes when running `systemctl start`)

Comment: yes, i have added to the binary file and restarted the service now - thank you.

But, I still see error regarding role-bindings when i try to configure dash-board.

unable to decode "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard-head.yaml": no kind "Role" is registered for version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1"


I believe, we have to configure the cluster role-bindings.
\\
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/plugin/pkg/auth/authorizer/rbac/bootstrappolicy/testdata/cluster-role-bindings.yaml

Comment: I have added the `--authorization-mode=RBAC` and restarted the api server.
Still, i see the error while i try to configure dashboard.
`unable to decode "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard-head.yaml": no kind "RoleBinding" is registered for version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1"`

Comment: I believe, we might need to setup role-binidings properly on the server.
I was referring to ` https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/plugin/pkg/auth/authorizer/rbac/bootstrappolicy/testdata/cluster-role-bindings.yaml`
to configure/create cluster role bindings.
any suggestions??

I have only issue with configuring dashboard, rest all the services on my kubernetes is running as expected.

Comment: You need to update kubectl to at least 1.6. You currently have 1.5. I've updated my answer to reflect that.