# Failed to discover supported resources

Tags: authentication, kubernetes, rbac, kubernetes-security

I am trying to Create User With Limited Namespace Access. created namespace named as test and also created Group:programmers, User:frontend. Generated credentials  for user:frontend by the help of following http://docs.bitnami.com/kubernetes/how-to/configure-rbac-in-your-kubernetes-cluster/

I created a role. Here is my role.yml

```
kind: Role
 apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
 metadata:
    namespace: test
    name: frontend-developer
 rules:
 - apiGroups: ["","extensions","apps"]
   resources: ["deployments","replicasets","pods"]
   verbs: ["get","list","watch","create","patch"]`
```

I created rolebinding. Here is role-binding.yml

```
kind: RoleBinding
 apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
 metadata:
   name: frontend-deploy
   namespace: test
 subjects:
 - kind: User
   name: frontend
   namespace: test
 roleRef:
   kind: Role
   name: frontend-developer
   apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

I am talking my deployment file as

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
 kind: Deployment
 metadata:
   name: nodefrontend
   namespace: test
 spec:
   replicas: 3
   template:
     metadata:
       labels:
         app: bookstore
     spec:
       containers:
       - name: nodeweb
         image: balipalligayathri/devops-develop
         ports:
         - name: http
           containerPort: 3000
           protocol: TCP
```

I am using following commands while creating the role and rolebinding

```
$ kubectl create -f role.yml
$ kubectl create -f role-binding.yml
```

frontend developer Role and frontend-deploy Rolebindings were created.

Again, i am using the command `kubectl create -f node-deployment.yml` for deployment creation. Deployment was created and deleted successfully. here, i didn't mention any user while creating the deployment.so, I am trying to create deployment with user by using the below command.

```
kubectl create -f node-deployment.yml --as=frontend --context=frontend-context
```

I am facing the error like this

```
Error from server (Forbidden):

<html><head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;url=/login?from=%2Fswagger-2.0.0.pb-v1%3Ftimeout%3D32s'/><script>window.location.replace('/login?from=%2Fswagger-2.0.0.pb-v1%3Ftimeout%3D32s');</script></head><body style='background-color:white; color:white;'>
    Authentication requiredhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/48164369/kubernetes-   1-8-dashboard-configurations-fails-with-error-no-kind-role-is-regi
    You are authenticated as: anonymous
    Groups that you are in:
    Permission you need to have (but didn't): hudson.model.Hudson.Read
    which is implied by: hudson.security.Permission.GenericRead
    which is implied by: hudson.model.Hudson.Administer    </body></html>
```

My doubt is: is there any necessity to mention the user in `deployment.yml` file?

Comment: Can anyone give me clear idea on how to work with RBAC using service accounts?Is Service accounts should have any security certificates?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a `serviceAccount`, take a look at this snippet:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: myAccount
```

bind it to your role:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: myBinding
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: frontend-developer
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: myAccount
```

and use it in your Deployment:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
 kind: Deployment
 metadata:
   name: nodefrontend
   namespace: test
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        ...
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: myAccount
```

Ref:

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/

Comment: I didn't mention service account in rolebinding.yml under subject section. Is it correct to add service account in deployment.yml file?, Is service accounts should have any security certifications ?

Comment: Is it should have both user and service account for a role in RBAC in kubernetes?

Comment: Use serviceAccount instead of user. I updated my answer.

Comment: In my example, Role don't have permissions for deleting deployment. How can i check that?

Comment: Added some more info.